# run multiple functions and save objects in a named list in r

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to figure out how to run multiple functions with different parameters and save the objects in a list and name each elements.
Use mtcars dataset as an example:

```
sel<- function(data, x){
    data %>% select(x)
}
vars <- c('disp', 'hp')
df.list<- map(vars, ~sel(data=mtcars, .x))
```

what I get is a list of dataframes. The question is how to return a list with each object named. For example, the first object is named 'disp', the second named 'hp'....
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Rename the list elements afterwards, something like `names(df.list) <- vars`?

Comment: What Uwe says. If you want to use a pipe, use `setNames()`